# Event Data Aggregation Using Kafka Streaming

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

```
public class UserEvent {
    int userId;
    long loginTime;
    long jobId;
    long jobAttachTime;
    long jobdetachTime;
    long workTime;
    long logoutTime;
    long activeTime;
    EventType eventType;
}
```

I have an application where events are sent on a Kafka topic based on user actions like login, job attach, job detach and logout.
Each event has some information in a `UserEvent` object along with `userId` and `eventType`, 
 for example a **Login** Event has `loginTime`;
  a **Job Attach** event has the properties `jobId`, `jobAttachTime`.
  Similarly a **Logout** event has the property `logoutTime`. 
My requirement is to aggregate information from all these events into one object after receiving the **Logout** event for each user.
So that after the **logout** event, the **UserEvent** object will have `loginTime`, `logoutTime`, calculated `workTime`, `activeTime` etc.
How could this be achieved using **Kafka KStreams and/or KTables**?

Answer (score 1):

In order to aggregate the UserEvents, you need a key(example : session id) to filter the sessions which is common across all the events. Let's say you have sessionID attached to each user event , which is unique for each session but same for all user events occured during that session.

It can be achieved using `GroupBy().aggregate()` in following way : (*considering you have session Id equivalent attribute which can be unique to use as a key*)

```
    // Let's say there is a  sessionID
KTable<String, UserEvent> userEventSummary = userEvents
                                  .groupBy(event -> event.get("sessionId"))
                                  .aggregate((userEventSummary,userEvent)->{
                                        userEventSummary = userEvent;
                                        if(new!= null){
                                            String loginEvent = new.get("eventType").get("eventName");
                                            if(loginEvent.equals("login")){
                                                userEventSummary.setLoginTime(new.getLoginTime());
                                            }
                                            if(loginEvent.equals("logOut")){
                                                long workTime = Math.abs(userEvent.getLogOutTime()-userEventSummary.getLoginTime());
                                                userEventSummary.setWorkTime(workTime);
                                                userEventSummary.setActiveTime(workTime);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        return userEventSummary;
                                   });

// if default value for logoutTime is 0, filter the user events which don't have logout time yet
KTable<String, UserEvent>  loggedOutEventSummary = userEventSummary.filter(event-> event.getLogOutTime()!= 0);
```

It will return the aggregated state for each user action filtered by user events which have Logout events.

Answer (score 0):

```
final KStream<Integer, UserEvent> kStream = builder.stream("test-topic");
kStream.groupByKey().aggregate(() -> new UserEvent(),
                (Integer userId, UserEvent userEvent, UserEvent userEventSummary) -> {
                    if (userEvent.getEventType().equals(EventType.LOGIN)) {
                        // Event Processing logic for Login event
                    } else if (userEvent.getEventType().equals(EventType.LOGOUT)) {
                        // Event Processing logic for Logout event
                    }
                    return userEventSummary;
                });
```